# Is it possible to add an image/variable into an email using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have been wondering if it is at all possible to modify the content of something in an email that is being sent with `window.open('mailto:test@email.com?subject=&body=')`.

I am hoping to be able to add a `div` from my html, either as is, or exported as a PDF somehow, and then have a variable from my script appear in the subject line of the email.

If this is not doable with normal Javascript, what could I use to do something like this, if it's at all possible? Would it be best done with PHP, or something like Ajax, jquery or the like?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in JavaScript, it can only be a server-side language.
You can upload the image to the server and sent from the server

Comment: Is there a server-side language you would recommend learning/using? I don't have much experience with server-side coding. Gotta find a place to start.